# How to set a opacity in textbox for background and foreground color in windows phone 7.1?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I want to set a opacity in textbox in windows phone 7.1. I want to set opacity 20% for the background with #503E28 color code and 50% for foreground with #3B2D1E color code in the textbox in windows phone 7.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the alpha channel into the colour code

```
<TextBox Foreground="#803B2D1E"
 Background ="#33503E28" ... />
```

I believe WP uses `ARGB` values, so the first value is `A` (alpha). Alternatively, you can style it using Expression Blend.

Comment: thank you very much.. @keyboardP.. and can you tell me how can i change a opacity value in color for forgroung and background color?...

Comment: and in read only textbox how can i  apply a forground and background color.. in wp7.1?

Comment: The first two numbers (`80` and `33`) represent the alpha value. To calculate the number, get the % value, divide it by 100 and multiply by 255 (since 255 is the highest value). Convert that number to hex (either by code or using an online converter) and that will be the first number. For example, you wanted 20% opacity, so that would be ((20/100) * 255) and the convert that result to hex (which is `33`). To apply the readonly colours, change the TextBox style as shown here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645061%28VS.95%29.aspx

Comment: thank you so much.. i have a one problem.. if i set a forground and background color to textbox its display fine and i also set this color from .cs page on gotfouse event then its slightly changed..

Comment: txtName.Background = new SolidColorBrush(new Color() { A =        0x15, R = 0x50, B = 0x3E, G = 0x28 }); i am changed using this way so its sligtly changed when i give it from design side and codebehind side... can you tell me why this is happened?..

Comment: When you create a new `Color`, the range for `A` is 0 to 255. Therefore, 20% would be `51` which is `0x33`. So change `A` from `0x15` to `0x33` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: What if you do this instead? `txtName.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(51, 80, 62, 40));`

Comment: this is also not working.. actually what i want to doing is.. first in intially textbox forground and backgroung color is above way and when i typed any text then both apacity change means background should be bit lighter and background slightly dark and after enter it should be in intially state... i want to do only that's why i need to change from codebehind in gotfocus and lostfocus..

Comment: sorry @KeyboardP " new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(51, 80, 62, 40));" is working... but how you count this Argb value, related to "3B2D1E" hex code?